# setupWithViewPager(android.support.v4.view.ViewPager) in TabLayout cannot br applied to (androidx.viewpager..widget.ViewPager)

Tags: java, android, android-support-library, android-appcompat, androidx

how to fix this error

> setupWithViewPager(android.support.v4.view.ViewPager) in TabLayout
>   cannot br applied to (androidx.viewpager..widget.ViewPager)

here is my class

```js
package org.apoce.app;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import org.apoce.app.fragment.RecentPostsFragment;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
public class PostActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView( R.layout.activity_post);
  FragmentPagerAdapter mPagerAdapter = new FragmentPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()) {
   private final Fragment[] mFragments = new Fragment[] {
     new RecentPostsFragment(),
   };
   @Override
   public Fragment getItem(int position) {
   return mFragments[position];
   }
   @Override
   public int getCount() {
    return mFragments.length;
   }
   @Override
   public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    return getResources().getStringArray(R.array.headings)[position];
   }
  };
  ViewPager mViewPager = findViewById(R.id.container);
  mViewPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);
  TabLayout tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tabs);
  tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
```

You are using androidx library and support libraries **together**.
You **can't** do it.

**Using androidx library**:

- Use **`import com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout;`** instead of `android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;`
  [The component](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/TabLayout.md) is included in the Material Components Library.
- Change the `android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity` to `androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity`;

**Using support libraries:**

- Change the `androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager` to `android.support.v4.view.ViewPager`
- Change the `androidx.fragment.app.Fragment` to `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`
- Change the `androidx.fragment.app.FragmentPagerAdapter` to `android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter`